# Remove chapter number from theorem number

Tags: numbering, theorems

Currently the document I'm facing has a few chapters which
contain subchapters.
Those sub/chapters are numbered as usual like 1.1, 1.2, 3.7, ....

One specific type of those subchapters shall not follow the default numbering but have its own numbers over the whole document. So in chapter 1 the passage of e.g. a theorem shall have number 1 (nothing else). In chapter 3 it is continued and has the number 2.

My current approach is using

```
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newtheorem{specialthm}{specialthm}[mycounter]
```

In general it works
but if it comes to using it like

```
\begin{specialthm}Some very interesting text
....
```

I get numberings like 0.1 and later on 0.2 - thus I'm more interested in the subsection number for this kind of `specialthm`. so i think my question boils down to: how can i remove the main (chapter) figure - in this case the zero - from `mycounter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You current code states that the theorem should be labeled as `<mycounter>.<theorem number>`. The leading `0` is the `mycounter` number and you probably never change that counter, so it stays 0. The `specialthm` theorem has its own counter called `specialthm`. So if you only like that number use:

```
\newtheorem{specialthm}{specialthm}
```

which give me the requested behavior, i.e. continuous numbering across chapters.
If this really doesn't work for you can redefine `\thespecialthm` which prints the theorem number:

```
\renewcommand*{\thespecialthm}{\arabic{specialthm}}
```

This sets the number to only be the theorem number.

Comment: it works! seems i just didnt know how to address those counters. what i also wanted to mention is: reseting the counter works by using \setcounter{specialthm}{0} to set to value 0