# Resetting newtheorem counter

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters

This one is probably straightforward, but I'm not missing something with the newtheorem environment and using newcounter.  I would like a new environment on its own counter like "Environment M.1", but I get "Environment M.0.1" in the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{M.\arabic{mycounter}}
\newtheorem{myenv}{Environment}[mycounter]
\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}[Some Stuff]
Here are some comments.
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to define a new counter -- `\newtheorem{myenv}` already creates the necessary counter `myenv`. Just redefine `\themyenv`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{myenv}{Environment}
\renewcommand*{\themyenv}{M.\arabic{myenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}[Some Stuff]
Here are some comments.
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect.  And right when you posted that I found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16282/remove-chapter-number-from-theorem-number)

Comment: @walleye: Indeed -- your question may not be an exact duplicate, but Martin's answer also covers your question.

Comment: @walleye: BTW, you provided a good minimal example!

Comment: To clarify, this is a `newtheorem` thing? Not every `newenvironment` defines a counter, right?

Comment: @Seamus: As far as I know, right.

Answer (score 3):

Some explanation what went wrong: `\newtheorem{myenv}{Environment}[mycounter]` tells LaTeX to number the theorem environment `myenv` “within” `mycounter`. This means that `\themyenv` is set to `\themycounter.\arabic{myenv}` and the `myenv` counter is reset whenever `mycounter` is incremented. The typical use of this is to number within sections or chapters. On the other hand, `\newtheorem{myenv}[mycounter]{mycounter}` tells LaTeX to use `mycounter` to number `myenv`.