# Number a theorem with subsection-number. thm-number, without chapter number

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I wish to number theorem in a report with x.y if the theorem is the y-th number in section x (of some chapter), without chapter number.
In other words, I want the theorem be numbered like `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`, but without chapter number.
I know this may be easy and have some duplicate, but I did not find any.

This is an example of what I hoped, and the content of each theorem is what I planned the number should be like.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\section{section 1.1}
\begin{theorem}
    I hope this will be thm 1.1.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{A}
\begin{theorem}
    I hope this will be thm 1.2.
\end{theorem}   
    
\section{1.2}
\begin{theorem}
    Theorem 2.1.
\end{theorem}

    
    
\chapter{chapter 2} 
\section{section 2.1}   
\begin{theorem}
    Theorem 1.1.
\end{theorem}   
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: How’s your reader supposed to know what theorem 1.1 you refer to? The one in chapter 1 or in chapter 4?

Comment: @egreg Many books use such enumeration. We can say theorem 1.1 in chapter x. Chapter number issue can be solved by a hyper-reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16283/277964, but add, e.g., `\arabic{section}.` before the `theorem` counter:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand*{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\section{section 1.1}
\begin{theorem}
    I hope this will be thm 1.1.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{A}
\begin{theorem}
    I hope this will be thm 1.2.
\end{theorem}   
    
\section{1.2}
\begin{theorem}
    Theorem 2.1.
\end{theorem}
   
\chapter{chapter 2} 
\section{section 2.1}   
\begin{theorem}
    Theorem 1.1.
\end{theorem}   
    
\end{document}
```

[image]